# How do I get wifi to work?

Tags: wireless, networking

I have 12.04 LTS on a Toshiba Portege R835-P56X.

I try to connect to my home network over wifi. It connects, but I can't access the Internet. I tried resetting the router, but that didn't work. Please help!

Comment: Does it work on a different OS, or with a Live CD/DVD?

Comment: Open a terminal by Ctrl+Alt+T, and type these separately: `lspci -nn | grep 0280`, `ifconfig` and `route -n`. Copy their outputs, edit your question, and paste the outputs in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the wifi card is blocked (Terminal)

**rfkill list wlan**     (for wifi)

OR

**rfkill list all**             (for wifi and bluetooth)

UNBLOCK:

**rfkill unblock wlan**     (for wifi)

OR

**rfkill unblock all**             (for wifi and bluetooth)

Restart the network:

**sudo service network-manager restart**

Also see:

http://www.iasptk.com/19593-ubuntu-1204-wifi-not-working-at-laptop-or-notebook-unblock-it

Comment: These commands are if the wireless card is turned off/blocked and if he can't connect/search for wireless networks. The person that asked the question can already connect to a network, but can't access the internet.